# RabbitMQ: management.ssl.certfile invalid, file doesn't exist or isn't readable

Tags: rabbitmq, lets-encrypt

I'm trying to config letsencrypt ssl to rabbitMq in a ubuntu EC2 instance, but I'm having problem with rabbitmq.conf file.

rabbitmq.conf:

```
management.ssl.port=15672
management.ssl.cacertfile=fullchain.pem
management.ssl.certfile=cert.pem
management.ssl.keyfile=privkey.pem
```

startup_err:

```
BOOT FAILED
===========

Config file generation failed:
06:40:00.676 [error] management.ssl.certfile invalid, file doesn't exist or isn't readable
06:40:00.677 [error] management.ssl.keyfile invalid, file doesn't exist or isn't readable
06:40:00.678 [error] management.ssl.cacertfile invalid, file doesn't exist or isn't readable
06:40:00.684 [error] Error generating configuration in phase validation
06:40:00.684 [error] management.ssl.certfile invalid, file doesn't exist or isn't readable
06:40:00.684 [error] management.ssl.keyfile invalid, file doesn't exist or isn't readable
06:40:00.684 [error] management.ssl.cacertfile invalid, file doesn't exist or isn't readable
In case the setting comes from a plugin, make sure that the plugin is enabled.
Alternatively remove the setting from the config.

init terminating in do_boot (generate_config_file)

Crash dump is being written to: /var/log/rabbitmq/erl_crash.dump...done
```

But the files do exist and I have made chmod 775 to all files.

Could someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

I successfully set up HTTPS for my RabbitMQ management web UI with a free certificate from Let's Encrypt.

I used Certbot version `1.17.0`. Certbot placed all the files related to the certificate in the `/etc/letsencrypt/archive/my_domain.com` folder and created corresponding symlinks in the `/etc/letsencrypt/live/my_domain.com` folder for our convenience.

Because RabbitMQ processes run under the `rabbitmq` account, you must ensure the `rabbitmq` account has permissions to read the certificate-related files *and* their parent folders. By default, only the `root` account can access the `/etc/letsencrypt/archive` and `/etc/letsencrypt/live` folders. To solve this problem, I created a new folder and cloned the `archive` and `live` folders into it.

```
sudo mkdir /etc/rabbitmq_letsencrypt
sudo cp -r /etc/letsencrypt/archive /etc/rabbitmq_letsencrypt
sudo cp -r /etc/letsencrypt/live /etc/rabbitmq_letsencrypt
```

Finally, I make `rabbitmq` the owner of the new folder so that RabbitMQ can read all the certificate-related files:

```
sudo chown -R rabbitmq:rabbitmq /etc/rabbitmq_letsencrypt
```

This is part of my configuration file:

```
management.ssl.port       = 15672
management.ssl.cacertfile = /etc/rabbitmq_letsencrypt/live/my_domain.com/chain.pem
management.ssl.certfile   = /etc/rabbitmq_letsencrypt/live/my_domain.com/cert.pem
management.ssl.keyfile    = /etc/rabbitmq_letsencrypt/live/my_domain.com/privkey.pem
```

As you can see, `management.ssl.cacertfile` must be mapped to the `chain.pem` file rather than the `fullchain.pem` file.

You should use absolute paths such as `/etc/rabbitmq_letsencrypt/live/my_domain.com/cert.pem` instead of relative paths such as `cert.pem`.

Comment: I have done exactly the above and still get the error. Annoying, "invalid, file doesn't exist or isn't readable" is 3 possibilities instead of one. But I can confirm that the user rabbitmq definitely has permissions to read that file!

Comment: @Anselan did you find a solution? I've seen your comments on a few threads now :) so I'm guessing you went down this road before me. Any solutions you can share?